# Calling goto() externally/manually

Tags: jquery, function, pagination

This question is specific to [jquery.pajinate.js](http://bit.ly/c9Riw7).  Basically it's a pagination plugin for jQuery that works great!  I'm actually trying to add in some [Unique URL](http://ajaxpatterns.org/Unique_URLs) functionality so that after jquery.pajinate() builds my pagination links, I can link to a specific page.  This seems logical especially if someone wants to share a specific page of something with someone else.

Inside of jquery.pajinate.js, there is the following code that executes when someone clicks another page link inside the "pajinated" code:

```
function goto(page_num) {
  ...
};
```

I've written the following custom code that will get the contents of my URL and then append "#page_num" when someone clicks a page link, producing **http://website.com/category/shorts/#page2**

```
var pageURL = window.location.href.split("#");
$('.page_link').click(function () {
  window.location.href = pageURL[0]+"#page"+$("span", this).text();
});
```

**QUESTION**

Now, I'd like to call the goto() function publicly and outside of the scope of the pajinate function.  So I'll need it to look something like this:

```
function after_page_loads() {
  if url contains "#pageX"
  goto(X);
}
```

I don't need help writing that function, just how to call the goto() from inside that function.  Right now I'm getting an error that says, "TypeError: $("#content").goto is not a function".  By the way, #content is the object I'm pajinate()-ing.

THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

The start_page option for the plugin determines which page to "open" on page load (or whichever event you dictate). See the paginated list title "Custom Start Page" in the [demo](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4151695/html/pajinate-0.2/examples/example1.html) for an example.